# Eclipse Memory Analyzer - Export values

Tags: java, memory, heap-dump, eclipse-memory-analyzer

I am currently looking for a method to export data in mass quantities from a hprof dump using eclipse memory analyzer.

The reason for this being is that the database that used to hold this data is now permanently unavailable so the only way of me recovering it is getting it out of the heap dump and programatically parsing it then re-inserting it into the database for re-use.

There are currently 700 records inside an array, I need to get the array index as well as the data inside the element.

I have attached an image to best explain
[image: an image]

Even if I could export the whole thing into some kind of HTML or XML file which i could interpret programatically that would be great, I think the rest would be fairly simple to complete however after 2 hours I am yet to find a way to do this.